# Pointer error message

Tags: c, xcode, macos, pointers

I apologize by advance if my question seems absolutely trivial, but I don't understand why if I run

```
int main(){
    int *count = 0;
    printf("%d",*count);
}
```

I have no input (using Xcode) and an error:

> Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = 0x0)

Could someone explain to me what this is?

Comment: By the way, @CarlNorum, I didn't mean to split hair, sorry if my comment sounded like so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is dereferencing a null pointer, which is undefined behavior: your `count` is a *pointer*, which means that it needs to point to a valid location before you can read from it:

```
int main(){
    int *count = malloc(sizeof(int)); // Give your pointer a valid location
    *count = 123;                     // This is valid now
    printf("%d", *count);             // prints 123
    free(count);                      // Don't forget to free allocated memory
}
```

Comment: just to test, if I put this code in a cpp file, I get at the line "int *count = malloc(sizeof(int));" cannot initialize a variable of type int * with an rvalue of type void *; Is there an equivalent for cpp file ?

Comment: @user1611830 That's because you use C++ compiler: in C++ a cast is required: `int *count = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` I did not put the cast, because it's not required in C.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `count` as a **pointer to an integer value** not as an integer value and you have initialized the pointer to be NULL (memory address 0).

You would want to do the following...

```
int main()
{
   int buffer = 0;
   int* count = &buffer;
   printf( "var %d = %d\n", buffer, *count );
}
```